# Adding increment to form input getting TypeError: qty_el is null

Tags: javascript, php, magento, increment

I´m trying to add increments in Magento grouped items, the code should be as follows but the javascript is returning TypeError: qty_el is null.
I think the problem should be when i pass the element id variable, but can´t solve this.
What am I missing? Is there another way to do this?
Hope someone could help me.

```
<div class="add-to-cart">
            <div class="qty-button form-group">

                <input type="text" name="super_group_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" id="super_group_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty() * 1  ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty group-qty form-control" />

                <div class="box-container">
                    <div class="box-icon button-plus"> 
                        <input type="button" onclick="incre(2,'super_group_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>')" class="qty-increase" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-icon button-minus">
                        <input type="button" onclick="decre(<?php echo json_encode ($i);?>,'super_group_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>')" class="qty-decrease" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function incre(qty_inc,idname)
{
    var qty_el = document.getElementById(idname);
    var qty = qty_el.value;

    if( !isNaN( qty )){
        if(qty_inc>0){
                qty_el.value = Number(qty) + qty_inc ;
            } else {
                qty_el.value++;
            }
      }

}

function decre(qty_inc,idname)
{
    var qty_el = document.getElementById(idname);
    var qty = qty_el.value;

            if(!isNaN( qty ) && qty > '0') {
                if(qty_inc>0){
                qty_el.value = Number(qty) - qty_inc;
                } else {
                    qty_el.value--;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Just add alert(idname) into the incre() and see what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try another way to increment decrement quantity on grouped products

```
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity:') ?></label>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('super_group_<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) && qty > 1 ) qty_el.value--;return false;" class="qty-decrease" > - </a>
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" id="super_group_<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo max($this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1, 1) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="var qty_el = document.getElementById('super_group_<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>'); var qty = qty_el.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) qty_el.value++;return false;" class="qty-increase" /> + </a>
```